# How to prevent SECUSO Privacy Friendly Net Monitor apps from shutdown without my permission

Tags: 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat

I download the SECUSO research group - Privacy Friendly Net Monitor from https://f-droid.org/packages/org.secuso.privacyfriendlynetmonitor/ and install on my Android 7 phone which is not rooted. I run it to monitor which apps is connecting and downloading at the background (regardless I am on wifi or my phone mobile data).

I notice that the Privacy Friendly Net Monitor will shutdown when the phone is screen off, which I never permit it to shutdown as I want it to continuously monitor all the apps including those from Google (such as Google Play Store app, which is famous for notoriously downloading at the background without user permission.)

So, how do I go about to prevent Privacy Friendly Net Monitor from shutdown or stop running without my permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the app is battery optimised, which means once the screen is off and [doze-mode](/questions/tagged/doze-mode)  kicks in, it is stopped.

From Settings → Battery → 3 dots menu on top right → all apps → Netapp → Don't optimize
(that's on Oreo, may vary a little on Nougat). Once you do that app will run till you stop it manually.

OP has clarified further

> For Nougat, find the options 'lock screen cleanup' or 'off screen cleanup' from Settings → Battery and choose the option 'Don't Close' for SECUSO Privacy Friendly Net Monitor.